# White Space above all activities

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: White Space above]

style.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.WSS503" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <!--<item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>-->
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

I dont know why but this white space is everywhere. I cant find the reason of that

Comment: did u solved the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Let your `Layout` take the space from the removed `ActionBar` with  `"android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

Comment: Where i have to put that?

Comment: in the layout of your parent view. I guess it's activity_main.xml in your case.